# Remove a subquery

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, query-optimization, subquery

I have this query

```
select 
    T1.local,
    m.Nombre as Marca, 
    T1.NombreLinea as Linea , 
    case  when T1.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) then 0 else -sum(T1.Cantidad) end as Cantidad,
    case  when T1.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) 
    --toma en cuenta los descuentos de las facturas que fueron anuladas
    then T1.TotalNeto 
    else isnull(T1.ImporteNeto,0) - isnull((select sum(importe) as importe 
                                            from GrimPosCon..Fact_Descuento (nolock) DD
                                            where DD.IdComprobante = T1.idComprobante  and T1.IdDim_Producto = IdDim_Producto
                                             and T1.IdDim_Medida = IdDim_Medida and T1.IdDim_Calidad = IdDim_Calidad 
                                             and exists 
                                                (
                                                select 1 
                                                    from GrimPosCon..ComprobanteReferencias (nolock) AA
                                                    inner join GrimPosCon..Fact_Comprobante (nolock) BB on aa.IdComprobanteCredito = BB.IdComprobante
                                                    where AA.IdComprobanteDebito = DD.IdComprobante
                                                    and BB.IdDim_ComprobanteTipo in (4,13,16,19)
                                                )
                                            ),0) end as IMPORTE, 
    T1.NombreFamilia as Familia
from 
#Query T1
inner join GrimPosCon..Dim_Marca(nolock) m on m.IdDim_Marca = T1.IDDim_Marca
Group by  
    T1.local, m.Nombre,T1.NombreLinea,T1.NombreFamilia,T1.TotalNeto,T1.IdComprobante, T1.IdDim_producto,
    T1.idDim_Medida,T1.ImporteNeto,T1.IdComprobanteTipo,T1.IdDim_Calidad
```

I want to remove the biggest subquery.
I tried to do `Left Joins where is not null`, but it gave me a different result.
How Can I modify that ?
I want the same result, but use some Joins, or something more faster than that subquery. According to the execution plan, that subquery takes the %35 of the total query, and takes almost 50 secs in running all query

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? What's the intended outcome?

Comment: I mean, I want the same result, but instead of got the subquery, I want to do some Joins, or something faster

Comment: EXISTS will be more efficient than LEFT JOIN / NOT NULL logic.

Comment: @ChrisGessler Only if it's for a single table subquery or not correlated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
select 
  T1.local,
  m.Nombre as Marca, 
  T1.NombreLinea as Linea , 
  case  when T1.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) then 0 else -sum(T1.Cantidad) end as Cantidad,
  case  when T1.IdComprobanteTipo in (21,23,26,28) 
  --toma en cuenta los descuentos de las facturas que fueron anuladas
    then T1.TotalNeto 
    else isnull(T1.ImporteNeto,0) - isnull(DD.importe,0)
  end as IMPORTE,
  T1.NombreFamilia as Familia
from 
  #Query T1
  inner join
  GrimPosCon..Dim_Marca(nolock) m on m.IdDim_Marca = T1.IDDim_Marca
  left join
  (
    select
      CC.IdComprobante,
      CC.IdDim_Producto,
      CC.IdDim_Medida,
      CC.IdDim_Calidad,      
      sum(importe) as importe 
    from
      GrimPosCon..Fact_Descuento (nolock) CC
    where
      exists 
        (
          select 1
          from
            GrimPosCon..ComprobanteReferencias (nolock) AA
            inner join
            GrimPosCon..Fact_Comprobante (nolock) BB on aa.IdComprobanteCredito = BB.IdComprobante
          where
            AA.IdComprobanteDebito = CC.IdComprobante
            and
            BB.IdDim_ComprobanteTipo in (4,13,16,19)
        )
    group by
      DD.IdComprobante,
      DD.IdDim_Producto,
      DD.IdDim_Medida,
      DD.IdDim_Calidad
  ) as DD on
      DD.IdComprobante = T1.idComprobante
      and
      DD.IdDim_Producto = T1.IdDim_Producto
      and
      DD.IdDim_Medida = T1.IdDim_Medida
      and
      DD.IdDim_Calidad = T1.IdDim_Calidad 
  Group by  
    T1.local, m.Nombre,T1.NombreLinea,T1.NombreFamilia,T1.TotalNeto,T1.IdComprobante, T1.IdDim_producto,
    T1.idDim_Medida,T1.ImporteNeto,T1.IdComprobanteTipo,T1.IdDim_Calidad,DD.importe
```

It may run faster or slower depending on your data.